# Inputting text value in text-field in specific format in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing iPhone application. I need to take input from user in textfield in fix format like xx-xxx-xxx. So I am not getting how to do this? Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: u need to visible the text 12-234-333 or  xx-xxx-xxx format

Comment: In textfield placeholder , mention this format. User may catch the point as the format should to xx-xxx-xxx.

Comment: I didn't get u,Actually when user start to input then input field should appear in this format like:  -   -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{


if (range.location == 10)    //this is calculate the overall string
 {
        return NO;
    }

    if ([string length] == 0)   //string length is `0` hide the keyboard
    {
        return YES;
    }

    if ((range.location == 2) || (range.location == 6) )    //apply the `-` between the overall string
    {
        NSString *str  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",textField.text];
        textField.text = str;
    }

}
```

Comment: in any queries, I am waiting for changes